# Numpy operations on ndarrays containing strings and numbers

Tags: python, r, numpy, multidimensional-array

This is my very first question on stackoverflow. So far all my questions had already been asked, but even after much research I couldn't find an answer to this one. So here goes:

I would like to do mathematical operations in numpy arrays for which I casted a dtype. This would be trivial in R but is complicated in python.

```
import numpy as np
from StringIO import StringIO
test = "a,1,2\nb,3,4"
data = np.genfromtxt(StringIO(test), delimiter=",", dtype=None)
```

This gives me:

```
print data
#array([('a', 1, 2), ('b', 3, 4)],
#      dtype=[('f0', '|S1'), ('f1', '<i8'), ('f2', '<i8')])
```

But then if I try to perform any mathematical operation on the numerical subset of data I get error messages:

```
subData = data[['f1','f2']]
print subData
# [(1, 2) (3, 4)]
subData+1
#TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'numpy.ndarray' and 'int'
```

or even:

```
subData + subData
#TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'numpy.ndarray' and 'numpy.ndarray'
```

The only solution I came up with is not a very elegant or practical one because I tend lose the column names and types as well as the original shape:

```
subData.view(int) + 1
```

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: For what it's worth, numpy's stuctured arrays aren't really meant for this sort of thing. They're arrays of C-like structs, not "spreadsheet-like" data.  The typical way to handle it is to hold each column in a separate array.  `pandas` is a much better choice for this, though. It's meant for "spreadsheet-like" data.

Answer (score 1):

Just to elaborate on my comment, structured arrays aren't exactly meant for this.  They're arrays of C-like structs.  They can be used to hold columns of different types, but it will become cumbersome quickly.  They're very useful for certain things, but "spreadsheet-like" data is not one of them. Typically, you'd just store each column as its own array when they have different types. (This is essentially what `pandas` does.)

This is because structured arrays *aren't* arrays where the columns have different types, they're arrays where *each item* is a sequence that has different types.

If you did want to convert all but the first column into a "normal" 2D array, you'd do something like this:

```
numeric_data = np.c_[[data[col] for col in data.dtype.names[1:]]]
```

However, ror data where each column is a different type, it's far better to use `pandas`.  It's meant for spreadsheet-like data.

```
from StringIO import StringIO
import pandas as pd

test = "a,1,2\nb,3,4"
data = pd.read_csv(StringIO(test), header=None)

print data[[1,2]] + 5
```

Comment: Thanks Joe. I was actually rather trying to avoid having to resort to Pandas. So I prefer the first option :) I still find it weird that I can't do something so simple easily. What are structured arrays meant for if not this?